# C# Use of unassigned local variables (int)

Tags: c#

I am wondering what I am doing wrong, as I am trying to make a menu, in which it needs to calculate three different courses together in predefined values, however I seem to be doing the conversions wrong, as I cant seem to make it work right.

```
    int a, b, c;
    textBox4.Text = (a + b + c).ToString();
    if (comboBox1.Text == "Tzatziki")
    {
    a = 35;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "Carpaccio")
    {
    a = 40;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "Bruscetta")
    {
    a = 30;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "Shrimp Cocktail")
    {
    a = 40;
    }
    if (comboBox2.Text == "Sirloin")
    {
    b = 225;
    }
    else if (comboBox2.Text == "Lamb")
    {
    b = 195;
    }
    else if (comboBox2.Text == "Salmon")
    {
    b = 170;
    }
    else if (comboBox2.Text == "Veggy")
    {
    b = 100;
    }
    if (comboBox1.Text == "Chocolate Cake")
    {
    c = 45;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "Pancakes")
    {
    c = 35;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "Waffles")
    {
    c = 40;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "Sundae")
    {
    c = 38;
    }

}
```

Would appreciate the advice, kinda new to C# programming :)

Comment: please start structuring your code...

Comment: Use switch-case.. makes your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can convert an integer, to its textual counterpart, you need to give it an initial value.

The reason why you get zero is because after you initialize variables (with zero), you immediately use them. In that sence the if-then-else patterns are useless.

---

A possible fix is to use `switch-case` patterns to ease coding and **after** you calculated `a`, `b` and `c`, set the text value:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
switch(comboBox1.Text) {
    case "Tzatziki" :
        a = 35;
        break;
    case "Carpaccio" :
        a = 40;
        break;
    case "Bruscetta" :
        a = 30;
        break;
    case "Shrimp Cocktail" :
        a = 40;
        break;
}
switch(comboBox2.Text) {
    case "Sirloin" :
        b = 225;
        break;
    case "Lamb" :
        b = 195;
        break;
    case "Salmon" :
        b = 170;
        break;
    case "Veggy" :
        b = 100;
        break;
}
switch(comboBox3.Text) {
    case "Chocolate Cake" :
        c = 45;
        break;
    case "Pancakes" :
    c = 35;
        break;
    case "Waffles" :
        c = 40;
        break;
    case "Sundae" :
        c = 38;
        break;
}
textBox4.Text = (a + b + c).ToString();
```

You probably made even a mistake for `c`, since you used `ComboBox1` again (I expect this should be `ComboBox3`. By using a switch-case structure, the code becomes more elegant.

---

A final problem with the code is what to do if no value has been entered in the combobox (or a different one from what you have checked). In the case I wrote above, the values will remain `0` (only the values corresponding to the `ComboBox` that has an unknown value). You can add a `defaut :` case in order to decide what to do then.

Comment: Cheers for the advice, I will do this, after I get some sleep, wrote the rest of the code in switch-case statements so don't know why I suddenly went for if statements anyway - guess that's what lack of sleep does to you :-/

Answer (score 2):

Give value to your variables and initialize them:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
```

And I think you need to move this line end of your `if / else-if` statements:

```
textBox4.Text = (a + b + c).ToString();
```

Comment: I tried that, but only lead to all results being 0, instead of the added values, that it should be.

Comment: why it should be ? you are not getting a value from anywhere.you just defining three local variables.